# How do I parse a timebased result using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I want to monitor highest CpuUsage from this result. How do I parse a `json` that changes its category on a time base?

```
{
  "MonitorHistory": "{\"2021-10-06T00:00:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.45\"},\"2021-10-06T00:01:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.57\"},\"2021-10-06T00:02:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.73\"},\"2021-10-06T00:03:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.6\"},\"2021-10-06T00:04:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.45\"},\"2021-10-06T00:05:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.57\"},\"2021-10-06T00:06:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.6\"},\"2021-10-06T00:07:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.65\"},\"2021-10-06T00:08:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.72\"},\"2021-10-06T00:09:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.57\"},\"2021-10-06T00:10:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.87\"},\"2021-10-06T00:11:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.67\"},\"2021-10-06T00:12:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.78\"},\"2021-10-06T00:13:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.72\"},\"2021-10-06T00:14:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.73\"},\"2021-10-06T00:15:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.92\"},\"2021-10-06T00:16:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.0\"},\"2021-10-06T00:17:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.23\"},\"2021-10-06T00:18:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.93\"},\"2021-10-06T00:19:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.98\"},\"2021-10-06T00:20:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.87\"},\"2021-10-06T00:21:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"0.95\"},\"2021-10-06T00:22:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.18\"},\"2021-10-06T00:23:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.08\"},\"2021-10-06T00:24:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.15\"},\"2021-10-06T00:25:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.37\"},\"2021-10-06T00:26:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.72\"},\"2021-10-06T00:27:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.6\"},\"2021-10-06T00:28:00Z\":{\"CpuUsage\":\"1.47\"}}"
}
```

My desired result is a collection of CpuUsage values like
`0.45 0.73 0.6...`

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you give an example of what you want your query to return? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @aidandeno I have no idea how to parse past `jq '.MonitorHistory'` the timestamp is dynamic I don't know how to sort past them. My desired result is a collection of CpuUsage values like `0.45 0.73 0.6...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max_by` to find the maximum according to a specific path.

If you want to retain the timestamp, convert the objects using `to_entries` to a `key`/`value` pair and find the maximum:

```
jq '.MonitorHistory | fromjson | to_entries | max_by(.value.CpuUsage | tonumber) | {(.key):.value}'
```

Otherwise, if you only need the highest number

```
jq '[.MonitorHistory | fromjson[].CpuUsage | tonumber] | max'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first parse the `MonitorHistory` json string to get it into a workable form. Then take advantage of the fact that json objects when enumerated in jq are in alphabetical order (since they appear to be ISO timestamps). Just pull the values from each of the entries. Since it's all just single property objects, just spit out the values.

```
.MonitorHistory | fromjson[][] | tonumber
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/k_IiAV6KmN)